# Is there a function to implement when dealing with django image or filefield?

Tags: python, django, django-models, operating-system, django-admin

I create a field which contain Imagefield in my models but when I am trying to add the image to the to the field in my admin page it is telling me function not implemented

This is how my models look like

```
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
 class Image(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
     img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')

     def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This is the exception that gives me

```
 OSError at /admin/imageapp/image/add/[Errno 38] 
 Function not implementedRequest Method:POSTRequest.    
 URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/imageapp/image/add/
  Django. Version:3.2.11
 Exception Type:OSError
 Exception Value:[Errno 38] Function not 
 implementedException.   
  Location:/data/data/com.termux/files/
        home/imagetest/lib/python3.10/site- 
         packages/django/core/files/locks.py, 
    line 117, in unlockPython.      
   Executable:/data/data/com.termux/
           files/home/imagetest/bin/ 
   pythonPython Version:3.10.2Python Path: 
   ['/storage/emulated/0/imagetest', 
  '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python310.zip', 
 '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10', 
 '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/lib- 
   dynload',  
   '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/
             imagetest/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
Server time:Fri, 21 Jan 2022 16:13:45 +0000
```

Comment: Maybe you need to sync migrate again?

Comment: Can you please  share your admin.py file so that i would have a look and help solve the issue ?